# Why does the TypeScript code not get any return value from the C# code?

Tags: c#, typescript, ajax

I call a C# method from TypeScript using $.ajax. Although I return a value, I don't get it. In the console just the message "result from RegionGrowing: " appears.

Here's the TypeScript code:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ShapeDetection/RegionGrowing",
            data: {
                points: points,
                faces: faces,
                mousex: pointer.x.toString(),
                mousez: pointer.z.toString()
            },
            success: (result) => {
                console.log("result from RegionGrowing: ", result);
                },
            dataType: "json"
        });
```

I simplified the C# code:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult RegionGrowing(SimpleShape simpleShape)
        {
            return Json("hello world");
        }
```

So I would have expected "result from RegionGrowing: hello world" to appear in the console.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in the C# code, to see if it got hit? (although apparently you do have a "success" result, so it's not a "not found" error)

Comment: I don't think that the problem is with the C# code. As a matter of fact "result from RegionGrowing: " was displayed, so I'd assume that the C# code was executed and then the execution returned to the TypeScript code, where the method specified in "success" was executed. But for some reason that is unknown to me, the parameter "result" did not contain "hello world".